# jQuery breaks dropdown navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I'm having issues with a bit of jQuery breaking the navigation in my company's Wordpress site.

I'm using this snippet of jQuery to change the default selection of a radio button in a form field (within a pricing calculator):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input[name=fieldname10_2][value='3']").prop("checked",true);
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would include the form, but it is being loaded via WP Plugin. Suffice to say that the code works, but when I have it loaded, the hover functionality of the dropdown navigation for the site is broken.

If it helps, the address for the page is http://72.41.28.254/wordpress/#pgtop

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

-Tyler

Comment: Add some quotes around the name attributes value. `[name='fieldname10_2']`

Comment: Thanks, I've done this to clean up the code. It doesn't seem to have any bearing on the issue, however.

Comment: What the browser console tells you?

Comment: Are you including this within a `$(document).ready()`, if not you may be causing a JS error before you run the rest of your code (e.g. the menu code)

Comment: I'm getting 1 console error:
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).popover is not a function

Comment: Quick note that may be helpful: the navigation breaks on any page where I've loaded the google API for jQuery. That seems to be where I'm having trouble.